# Changing data binding in DataTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I need to modify one of the bound properties in my `DataTemplate`. The template is defined like this (relevant portion only):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyImageTemplate">
  <Image>
    <Image.Source>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyImageConverter}">
        <Binding Path="Source" />
        <Binding Path="TransparencyColor" />
        <Binding Path="TransparencyTolerance" />
      </MultiBinding>
    </Image.Source>
  </Image>
</DataTemplate>
```

Depending upon a condition, I need to change first binding from **Source** to another property **Source2**.  Having spent the better part of the afternoon with this, I can't make the following simple code of my `DataTemplateSelector` work:

```
Public Class MyDataTemplateSelector
  Inherits DataTemplateSelector

  Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(item As Object, container As DependencyObject) As DataTemplate
    Dim DT = DirectCast(Application.Current.FindResource("MyImageTemplate"), DataTemplate)
    Dim Control = DirectCast(DT.LoadContent(), FrameworkElement)

    Dim MB = BindingOperations.GetMultiBinding(item, System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty)
    Dim Source2Binding As New Binding(NameOf(ImageVM.Source2))

    Dim MB2 As New MultiBinding With {.Converter = MB.Converter}
    MB2.Bindings.Add(Source2Binding)
    MB2.Bindings.Add(MB.Bindings(1))
    MB2.Bindings.Add(MB.Bindings(2))

    Control.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, MB2)

    Return DT
  End Function
End Class
```

I have confirmed that it doesn't even assign this newly created `MultiBinding` to Image's Source property. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LoadContent()` method creates an instance of the `Image` element that you have defined in the template. You are then setting the properties of this specific instance and return the unmodified template that you have defined in the XAML. The Image element that you modify in the `SelectTemplate` method will then be eligible for garbage collection immediately and will never be used.

So this approach won't work. You need to return a completely different `DataTemplate` from the method. You can't base a `DataTemplate` on another one. You might as well get rid of the `DataTemplate` from your XAML and use the [XamlReader.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a `DataTemplate` dynamically in your `DataTemplateSelector`. Check my answer here for an example:

[Combining DataTemplates at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751373/combining-datatemplates-at-runtime/44757321#44757321)

Your current approach *applies* the template and throws away the result.

Comment: Hmm... Makes sense. My impression was that `LoadContent()` would load the content *within* the `DT` object (much like `XmlDocument`'s `Load`). Obviously I was wrong. For now I have defined two identical `DataTemplate`s within XAML, which only differ by that one property. I return the appropriate one based on the condition. Thanks for your input.