# How to pass a ConverterParameter into a HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have two `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s that are identical, except for the `ConverterParameter` used for the `ItemsSource` property:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key ="Template1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Converter ={StaticResource DemoConverter}, ConverterParameter='One'}">
  ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key ="Template2" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Converter ={StaticResource DemoConverter}, ConverterParameter='Two'}">
   ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

How can I avoid the redundancy (replaced above by `...`)? I would like to have only one template that I can pass the (static) `ConverterParameter` to. Something like this (with **PARAMETER** placeholder):

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key ="Template" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Converter ={StaticResource DemoConverter}, ConverterParameter={PARAMETER}">
   ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And, in the "consuming" code I would write something like (with another **PARAMETER** placeholder):

```
<TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectTreeEditItem, PARAMETER=One}" ...></TreeView>
```

or

```
<TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectTreeEditItem, PARAMETER=Two}" ...></TreeView>
```

How can this be achieved? A suitable (although sub-optimal) solution would be to have two "wrapper" templates that reference one common template (setting the parameter from there, if setting the parameter as part of the `ItemTemplate` definition is the problem), but I wouldn't know how to do that either :o/

Answer (score 0):

> How can this be achieved?

By defining the templates *programmatically* using the `XamlReader.Load` method or the `FrameworkElementFactory` class. Please see my answer here for an example:

[Combining DataTemplates at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751373/combining-datatemplates-at-runtime/44757321#44757321)

You can't do something like "pass the (static) `ConverterParameter`" to another template in XAML. I am afraid this is not supported by the markup language.