# How to bind booleans to DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, telerik-grid

I have this DataTemplate for my RadGridView with a binding:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StatusTemplate">
    <local:StatusIndicator Style="{StaticResource StatusIndicator}" IsEnabled="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I'm using it on my GridViewDataColumn like this, where I bind booleans from my *ItemsSource*:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Enabled}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource StatusTemplate}" />
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Connected}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource StatusTemplate}" />
```

But the *Enabled* and *Connected* properties assigned to the *DataMemberBinding* is not working,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you won't be able to use the same `DataTemplate` for both columns. The binding path cannot be "injected" into the template in XAML which means that will need to create a unique `DataTemplate` with a specific binding path for each column:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Enabled}">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:StatusIndicator Style="{StaticResource StatusIndicator}" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Connected}">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:StatusIndicator Style="{StaticResource StatusIndicator}" IsEnabled="{Binding Connected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

If the `DataTemplate` is more complicated, you might consider creating the templates and replace the binding path programmatically:

[Combining DataTemplates at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751373/combining-datatemplates-at-runtime/44757321#44757321)