# DataGrid with cell template bound to array only shows data from first column?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am having trouble getting a cell template to work with a DatagridTemplateColumn.  The displayed output shows all columns filled with the data from the first column for each row.

If I set the cell's text binding to {Binding [2].Text}, it shows the data for the 3rd column in all columns, so I think I need some way in the cell template to get the index.   I've tried setting the binding to {Binding [{DisplayIndex}].Text}, but then I get " BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object'"

PS:  I have to use a DataGridTemplateColumn because I will be doing more complicated displays in the future.

Here is the relevant xaml:

```
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyCellTemplate" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyCellTemplate}" Header="Col1" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyCellTemplate}" Header="Col2" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyCellTemplate}" Header="Col3" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Binding Data:

```
        public ObservableCollection<string[]> TableItems { get; set; } 
        ...
        TableItems.Add(new string[]{"A","B","C"};
        TableItems.Add(new string[]{"D","E","F"};
        TableItems.Add(new string[]{"G","H","I"};
```

When I run my program, The data for all the columns is the same as the first column in each row.  e.g.:

Starting data:

```
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
```

Resulting output:

```
A,A,A
D,D,D
G,G,G
```

Expected output:

```
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
```

EDIT: -----------------------------------

A little more information:  THis xaml works, but obviously I would like to employ a common cell template.

```
                 <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="col1" > <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].Text}" /></DataTemplate></DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate></DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="col2" > <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding [1].Text}" /></DataTemplate></DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate></DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="col3" > <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding [2].Text}" /></DataTemplate></DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate></DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: If you are not going to auto-generate the columns, then each column needs to be explicitly created.  That includes telling each column what its data source is, thus the need for unique data bindings.  You can do a common style for the cell format (look and feel), but not for the data.

Comment: encapsulate the array into object, and bind to that object. like object contains 3 property, and make observable collection of that object and bind to propeties of that objects

Answer (score 0):

> This xaml works, but obviously I would like to employ a common cell template.

You can't since the binding paths differ between the columns. There is no support for doing something like `{Binding [{DisplayIndex}].Text}` in XAML.

What you can do is to create the three templates programmatically using the `XamlReader.Parse` method: [Combining DataTemplates at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751373/combining-datatemplates-at-runtime/44757321#44757321)