# Wpf reuse DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

in my xaml code I got two places which look very similiar and I'm trying to refactor them to not have duplicated code, but turns out it's not that easy...

```
                   <DataTemplate >
                       <Image Width="16" Height="16" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
                           <Image.Style>
                               <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                   <Style.Triggers>                                           
                                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TypeDescription}" Value="Matlab/Simulink">
                                           <Setter Property="Source" Value="xxx.png"/>
                                       </DataTrigger>
                                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TypeDescription}" Value="Python">
                                           <Setter Property="Source" Value="yyy.png"/>
                                       </DataTrigger>
                                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TypeDescription}" Value="High Speed Function">
                                           <Setter Property="Source" Value="zzzpng"/>
                                       </DataTrigger>
                                   </Style.Triggers>
                               </Style>
                           </Image.Style>
                       </Image>
                   </DataTemplate>
```

and

```
<DataTemplate DataType="dxg:GridCellData">
          <Image Width="16" Height="16" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
            <Image.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Data.TypeDescription}" Value="Matlab/Simulink">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="xxx.png"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Data.TypeDescription}" Value="Python">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="yyy.png"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Data.TypeDescription}" Value="High Speed Function">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="zzz.png"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            </Image.Style>
          </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Notice the only difference is the path of the binding. I'm trying to move this `datatemplate` to another file like resources and just reuse it, but the path of the binding is really making things complicated. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: I would probably try to set the datacontext of wherever the datatemplate is used to the "Data" part of the binding in the second example. Then you would be able to use the first example's binding for general usage.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't just replace the binding path and reuse the rest of the template in pure XAML because templates must be defined as-a-whole.

What you can do is to define the template programmatically using the `XamlReader.Parse` method:

[Combining DataTemplates at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751373/combining-datatemplates-at-runtime/44757321#44757321)

You may then simply replace a part of the `string` that you pass to the `Parse` method before you add the templates to your `ResourceDictionary`.